# Python function that corrects a email domain

Tags: python, regex, function

Okay, I have this function **construct_email(name, domain):**

```
def construct_email(name, domain):
    if domain == True:
        print 'True'
    else:
        print'None'
    return name + "@" + domain
```

This function isn't big or anything, it's suppose to output an email address. 
But I also have this other function `correct_domain(domain):` that is suppose to check the domain name that's been input in `construct_email(name, domain):`

```
import re
def correct_domain(domain):
    if re.search(r'^\.|\.$', domain) or re.search(r'\.\.', domain):
        return False
    elif re.search(r'\.', domain):
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

My question is, how do I do this?

Comment: You say `correct_domain()` is _supposed_ to check the domain name. What _does_ it do? Give some sample input and expected and actual output.

Comment: It's suppose to make sure that email domains does not contain a . at the beginning or end.
I.E .blabla@outlook.com.
and that it doesnt contain 2 . 
I.E blabla@outlook..com
and that the email has atleast 1 dot
I:E blabla@outlook.com

Comment: In `construct_email` you should never compare a variable to a boolean. Simply say `if domain:` instead of `if domain == True:`

Comment: So what happens when you call `correct_domain()`? What's the actual problem? What's going wrong? You need to provide some examples.

Comment: OKay thanks Josh! 

But how do I make construct_email(name, domain) call correct_domain(domain) when i run construct_email(name, domain) and type in My_name = "chris" my_email = construct_email(myname, 'outlook.com')

Answer (score -2):

If I'm understanding you correctly:

```
import re

def construct_email(name, domain):
    if not check_domain(domain):
        return False
    return name + "@" + domain

def check_domain(domain):
    dots = re.findall(r"\.", domain)
    if (len(dots) != 1) or domain.startswith(".") or domain.endswith("."):
        return False
    return True

def main():
    while True:
        email = construct_email(raw_input("Name: "), raw_input("Domain: "))
        if email:
            break
        print "Bad Domain, try again...\n"

    print email
    #other code here...
```

Comment: Thank you for your answers! It has helped me alot. I actually figured it out.

def construct_email(name, domain):

    if correct_domain(domain):
        print 'True'
    else:
        print'None'
    return name + "@" + domain

import re
def correct_domain(domain):
    

    if re.search(r'^\.|\.$', domain) or re.search(r'\.\.', domain):
        return False
    elif re.search(r'\.', domain):
        return True
    else:
        return False